# Is the phrase ~in x years inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage, range-inclusion

Is the phrase ~in x years, such as "The first revenue drop in x years," inclusive or exclusive of the last year there was a revenue drop?

For instance, given this scenario:

2000 - revenue decrease

2001 - revenue increase

2002 - revenue increase

2003 - revenue increase

2004 - revenue increase

2005 - revenue decrease

Would this be the first revenue drop in 5 years or 6? I thought this would be referred to as the first revenue drop in 5 years, with 2001 being 1 year from the decrease, 2002 being 2 years from the decrease, and so on. However, I've come across a book that refers to this as the first revenue drop in 6 years (2000 - 2005, inclusive). Which would be the correct description of the scenario?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127708/discussion-on-question-by-ki-is-the-phrase-in-x-years-inclusive-or-exclusive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is exclusive of the first revenue drop.

“In” refers to a period, and being the “first” in that period implies that there wasn’t another of the same kind within that period.

Conversely, if the period stretched to the time when there was a (previous) revenue drop, the current drop wouldn’t be the first.

Comment: Absolutely, if the last time I went on  holiday was in June 2015 and it is now July 2021 I can say "I haven't been on holiday in six years" but if my last holiday was in August 2015 I can only say "I haven't been on holiday in five years". It's a bit like calculating a person's age at death. If they died before their birthday in a given year you have to subtract the year of birth from the year in which they had their last birthday to get their age rather than subtract their birth year from their death year.